# How to avoid lock screen event during monkey test

Tags: android, lockscreen, monkey

i am running monkey tests and i am facing issues with lock screen.

i have tried running tests with default command as below

"monkey -p com.xyz -v 1500000 -s 10000 --throttle 15000"

The tests start fine but eventually get to lock screen and thereby never able to unlock as i have alphanumeric key code as password which is very hard to guess by random events of monkey. 
i just want the monkey to run only on app and ignore the lock screen events completely

i am enabling Never go to sleep from settings, please let me know if i can avoid monkey to stop pressing the power key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own python script. Please take a look at [a simple monkeyrunner program](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#SampleProgram%20a%20simple%20monkeyrunner%20program) from Android doc and an example from this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTesting/article.html#monkeyrunner). When you write the sript don't use these types of events:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_POWER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
device.press('KEYCODE_POWER', 'DOWN')
device.press('KEYCODE_POWER', 'UP')
```

which are reponsible for screen lock (more [key codes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)). In order to run your own script use:

```
mokeyrunner srcipt_name.py
```

Another solution could be avoiding **s** (pseudo-random number generator) flag in **adb shell monkey** command. Then use interesting flags except for **--pct-syskeys**  (These are keys that are generally reserved for use by the system, such as Home, Back, Start Call, End Call, or Volume controls.) More flags you find in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html